# Are we allowed to distribute our App Showdown entries prior to submission?

Tags: application-development

Are we allowed to distribute our App Showdown entries prior to submission for testing and feedback purposes, or is the submission supposed to be the first people see of them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Absolutely, you can release your code and get people excited about it and using it at any time.  In fact, we would highly encourage participants to do this, as it will give you excellent feedback to help improve your app before the final submission deadline.

Comment: seeing the people i think the competetion would be good